# SVG, forming lines into an image

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I'm forming an image in SVG from a bitmap using svgwrite and python where each line is rotated by theta around a common origin into a fan like-pattern. Currently this image is running around 10 MB for 128 lines largely because the excessive amount of floating point retained in the 79000+ line segments (one line segment per pixel).

[image: ScanConverted Image]

**I'd like to get the image size down significantly by drawing a single line from the origin out to the end-point and then stretch one line 'image' over that SVG line. Is this possible using SVG?** Beyond that, I'm open to any suggestion that might get the size down significantly and so I later I can animate the lines in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution (see **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06pozgxr/2/)**):

1. Slice the image up  in the number of strips you need. For the example in the linked fiddle, I used ImageMagick as follows to cut up a 128x128 PNG image into 128 vertical strips:
   `convert image.png -crop 1x128 +repage +adjoin strip-%d.png`
2. Convert all the image strips to data URI format and embed them in the SVG. I used this bash one-liner:
   `for i in strip-*.png; do echo "data:image/png;base64,$(openssl base64 < $i | tr -d '\n')"; done > data-uris.txt`
3. In the SVG, use the `transform()` attribute on the `image` strip elements to rotate them to the required degree.

For a 128x128 PNG icon of 16.4KB, I end up with an SVG file of 128.1KB. Most of that is the base64-encoded image data (the total size of the 128 PNG strips is already 85.1KB). It could be further reduced a little by rounding of some floats, but I don't think there's a whole lot to be gained.

There might be another approach possible where you embed the image as a whole, and reference another clipped section of the same image over and over, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: In the case of the JPEG2000 source file, I can just pull out the intensity values directly, but I like these embedded image strips. I just need to figure out how to handle them in python.

Comment: Got it. It's a little painful in python's svgwrite, because things aren't particularly well documented, but it works. Gets the file size down to 130KB